# How to upload photos/pictures to Zoom API using Python (multipart/form-data) with JWT?

Tags: python, multipartform-data, request-headers, zoom-sdk

I have been racking my brains trying to get this to work with Python. I see you can do this using Curl and JavaScript, but I prefer not to leave Python. Reading the documents (though, they are pretty bare), it says you must simply format the data in the headers as `multipart/form-data` and send the file as a binary.

```
import requests

userid = 'myuserid@place.com'
url = 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/{0}/picture'.format(userid)
jwt_token = '<supersecretkey>'
filepath = '/Users/me/Pictures/myprofilepic.jpg'

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(jwt_token)
}

files = [
  ('pic_file', open('<filepath>','rb'))
]

response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, files=files)

print(response.status_code)
```

This example, however, does not work. I keep getting 500 errors. I opened a support case with Zoom and received this exact same code to run. I tried to tackle this myself by formatting and setting my boundaries.

```
import requests
import binascii
import os
import base64

jwt_token = '<supersecretkey>'
filepath = '/Users/me/Pictures/myprofilepic.jpg'

def encode_image_base64(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as file:
        data_read = file.read()
        data = base64.b64encode(data_read)
    return data

def base64_encode_multipart_formdata(name,filename,content_type):
    base64image = encode_image_base64(filename)
    boundary = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16)).decode('ascii')
    body = '--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="{1}"; filename="{2}"\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n{4}\r\n--{0}--'.format(boundary,name,filename,content_type,base64image)
    content_type = "multipart/form-data; boundary={}".format(boundary)
    return( body, content_type)

def main():
    name = 'pic_file'
    content_type = 'image/jpeg'
    body , ct = base64_encode_multipart_formdata(name,filepath,content_type)
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': '{}'.format(ct),
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(jwt_token)
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
    print(response.status_code)
```

This does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out, `multipart/form-data` DOES NOT WORK for Zoom API Photo Upload but instead, you must remove Content-Type and replace that with `'Accept': 'application/json'`. Simple change but voila! it will now upload photos.

```
import requests

userid = 'myuserid@place.com'
jwt_token = '<supersecretkey>'
filepath = '/Users/me/Pictures/myprofilepic.jpg'

url = 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/{0}/picture'.format(userid)

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(jwt_token),
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           }
files = {'pic_file': open(filepath, 'rb'))}

response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
print response.content
```

I hope this saves some headaches for people that are dealing with the Zoom API.

Comment: Can't believe the official documentation - https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/user/methods/#operation/userPicture is incorrect. You are a lifesaver, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is the same solution, but for PowerShell?
I tried to do this, but got an error 500:

```
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer JWT_KEY")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/id/picture' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Body '{"pic_file":"C:/test/pic.jpg"}'
```

UPDATE.
Found a solution on PowerShell 7.0:

```
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer JWT_KEY")
$Form = @{pic_file     = Get-Item -Path '.\\test.jpg'}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/id/picture' -Method POST -Headers $headers -Form $Form
```

But I would like to find a solution on PowerShell 5.0